# Best Rails 3.1 practice to complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given:

(models):

```
Contract (has_many :invoices, belongs_to :user)
Invoice (belongs_to :contract)
```

This way, for example:

```
my_contracts = Contract.where(user_id: current_user.id) #=> [#<Contract id: 1, title: "1">, #<Contract id: 2, title: "2">]
```

In this case we have two Contracts for User. And each of Contracts have multiple number of Invoices.

Now we need to gather all Invoices for each of contracts and sort them by 'updated_at'.
Something like:

```
all_invoices = my_contracts.map{|i| i.invoices.sort_by(&:updated_at)}
```

but using ActiveRecord.

How it could be done right?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it is not bad, just use includes to get eager loading of the invoices instead of lazy (n+1) loading

```
contracts = Contract.where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:invoices)
# or this might do the same => current_user.contracts.includes(:invoices)
invoices = contracts.map{|i| i.invoices }

invoices.sort_by(&:updated_at).each do |invoice|
    # ....
end
```

try this and also what David Sulc posted, view the generated sql and experiment with the result in rails console; using joins vs includes has very different behavior, depending on situation one maybe better than the other

see also

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
Invoice.joins(:contracts).where(user_id: current_user.id).order(:updated_at)
```

Arel isn't a strong suit of mine (still need to work on it), but if this doesn't work, it should at least get you closer to the answer.

Comment: not sure but `.order(:updated_at)` might give an ambiguous error for updated_at since it is on both contracts and invoices table? `.order("invoices.updated_at")` might be needed

Comment: That's true. It's always best to try these out in a rails console with `Invoice.joins(:contracts).where(user_id: current_user.id).order(:updated_at).to_sql` and see the generated SQL. (And you should naturally have test cases checking everything ;-) )